# Firebase email and password authorization

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-assistant

I'm trying to connect firebase to my project, but there is no button for authorization by email and password.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried enabling "Enable Email/Password sign-in"?

Comment: @Christian Paul Andaya 
Yes, I'm trying to turn it on. The firebase site has email and password authentication enabled.

Comment: Choose Authenticate using a custom authentication system ! It's a new interface, it doesn't contain all the services.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check this [Authenticate with Firebase on Android Using a Custom Authentication System](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth#java_3).

> After a user signs in for the first time, a new user account is created and linked to the credentials—that is, the user name and password, phone number, or auth provider information—the user signed in with. This new account is stored as part of your Firebase project, and can be used to identify a user across every app in your project, regardless of how the user signs in.